# DB benchmarking - cluster vs instance?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, benchmarking

Say I want to benchmark results of a configuration of two databases (index-related to be more exact) and compare their differences.

What would I need to look out for between running the test of either two server instances side by side or a two databses on same cluster? For example, if I had two instances, it wouldn't make sense to have both online at the same time while performing tests since their activity will greatly influence the benchmark result.

Answer (score 1):

The question is so general that all that can be given are a few general comments:

- To test the performance difference between two configurations, everything else should be identical. That's usually easier to achieve if you run both tests on the same machine (of course you would suspend all kind of concurrent activity that is not part of the test).
- Run each test several times to be sure that the result is repeatable.

Don't forget that a performance test result is only relevant for the environment where it was performed, so keep your test environment as close to the target environment as you can.